# How can I delete duplicate cells in excel based on the cell next to them?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete duplicate rows based on the value that I have in the cell next to them but im new to vba and im having problems writing the code.
My excel is like this:

> 1 9789646122277   1392
>
> 2 9789646122277   1393
>
> 3 9789641570455   1389
>
> 4 9789641570455   1394
>
> 5 9786005383270   1391
>
> 6 9789645545268   1388
>
> 7 9789646761995   1395
>
> 8 9789646761995   1393
>
> 9 9789646761995   1391

The vba has to find the duplicates (for example 9789646122277), when found, it should compare the number on the cell next to them (1393 and 1392) and then delete the duplicate that has the less value on the side.
The result would be :

> 1 9789646122277   1393
>
> 2 9789641570455   1394
>
> 3 9786005383270   1391
>
> 4 9789645545268   1388
>
> 5 9789646761995   1395

Comment: If you are *'having problems writing the code'* then post the code you have written and explain the error. Don't expect someone else to write your code (i.e. *do your job*) for you.

Comment: Try recording the first step: delete the record you want, then [study the code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx#odc_Office14_ta_GettingStartedWithVBAInExcel2010_ModifyingTheRecordedCode) a bit - remove all `Activate` and `Select` statements, add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module, and attempt to create a [For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx) loop. If you run into problems update your question with specific details

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because '*im having problems writing the code*' is **not** a specific programming problem and adding narrative debris like '*im new to vba*' does nothing to change that. Please abide by the [rules and guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) that **you agreed to** when you joined this community.

Comment: As a starting point, I would do a sorted list. If the data you have above is in column A, B and C then sort on B then C.  Once you have your sorted list Sequence through each row comparing neighboring rows. If a match is found delete the first one. Keep sequencing through the list until no deletions take place then sort again to get rid of the blanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
Sub SiftData()
Dim i, j, toti As Integer

toti = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).Offset(Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown), 0)).Count - 1

For i = toti To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then GoTo nexti
        For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) Then
                If Cells(i, 2) > Cells(j, 2) Then
                    Cells(j, 2).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
                    Else: Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
                End If
            End If
        Next j
nexti:
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What variable types are `i` and `j`? and what happens to **`toti`** if there are 1 M rows? The `GoTo` statement is not advisable (can esaily be replace with a more intuitive flow in logic like `If Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then`). Also, the OP didn't provide enough details for you to properly qualify all ranges and provide a solid working solution

Comment: Also, `vbNullString` is preferred to `""`. To answer paul's rhetorical question on your types of i and j, they're both `Variants`. `Dim ' ' as ' '` is far preferred to multi-dim's on a single line. Further, `Integer` is known to cause issues with overflow errors. Use `Long` variables instead. Finally, try running your code with a few hundred thousand rows... it is going to take a very long time. Your loop is exponential in size. It doesn't scale well and is very inefficient. A dictionary and class would make short work of the task.

Comment: i and j are both integers as declared in the the second line. I could have declared them all as long, but since this was intended to be can example for the OP, I simply used an integer. The OP didn't state how many lines he was intending on iterating through, so again, I just gave OP a place to start, since they said they were new to VBA.

Comment: It's good that you're trying to help, but if the OP didn't make any attempt to code it implies they don't have the most basic knowledge needed to understand any response, including not providing the sheet name that we need to work with. Assuming the Activeworksheet like you did provides a brittal solution. Also, your **intent** was to declare `i` and `j` as integers, but as @BrandonBarney mentioned, that statement declares them implicitly as Variants; you need to specify each type: `Dim i As Long, j As Long, toti As Long`, and always use longs instead of ints - that's what VBA does